# jquery manipulation post page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using a script on an ecommerce website that shows or hide a free shipping stamp based on a number(price). Initially the stamp shows for all products and i hide it where necessary. My problem is, the script reads from the 'regular price' and will display the stamp accordingly, but i have products with promotions that hides the regular price and displays the promo price then bringing the actual price of the product under the appropriate limit and i can't figure out a way to hide the free shipping stamp on those particular items.

I'm using the following to remove the tag if the price goes under 99, but with my hackish promotion price display, i cant figure out how to read that post load promo price display to apply the function as needed. I've tried replicating this script and applying it to the promo price div to no avail. Any suggestions as to how i can read a divs numerical contents post load and hide the stamp? I'm beginner to intermediate when it comes to jquery so help in layman's terms would be helpful.

```
$('#results-table .redprice, #pp-wrap #big-price span').each(function(){
var $this = jQuery(this);
var number=$this.html();
number=number.substring(1);
number=parseFloat(number);
    if(number > 50){$this.parents('div.grid3wrapper, div.list3wrapper, #pp-wrap').addClass('over50');}
    if(number > 99){$this.parents('div.grid3wrapper, div.list3wrapper, #pp-wrap').addClass('over99');}
    if(number < 99){$this.parents('div.grid3wrapper, div.list3wrapper, #pp-wrap').addClass('under99').removeClass('freeshipping');}
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to use html attribute for the real price.
something like

```
<span realP=12>16</span>
```

and then getting the number would be easier:

```
var number = $(this).attr("realP");
```

goog luck

Comment: the problem with that is the real price stays the same while the promo price display onLoad.

|i.e.
Regular Price: $129.95
25% Off Sale Price: 
Starting At: $97.46|

i could add an attribute to the realP and promoP but im not sure how that argument would look.